# How to query inside "bytea" data type column with postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, operators, byte

I am trying to use AND operator between variables with the type of byte. the error below is bugging me.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: bytea & bytea
LINE 3: WHERE (doctors.schedule & '\x0000000000000000000000000000000...
                                ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

let's say those two variables are:

```
v = b'\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

c = b'\xff\xff\xc0\x03\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfc\x03\xff\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

any idea how to solve this?
I appreciate it in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `&` operator for `bytea`. After all, `bytea` stands for "byte array", not for "bit array".

There is, however, a function to test if a certain bit is set:

```
SELECT get_bit('\xF0'::bytea, 4);

 get_bit 
═════════
       1
(1 row)
```

This would get the value of the fifth bit from the lower end: 111**1**0000

If you want to access the individual bits of a value, you should use the data type `bit varying`. That will also give you the bitwise operations you'd expect:

```
SELECT B'11110000' & B'00011000';

 ?column? 
══════════
 00010000
(1 row)
```

(A string literal wit preceding `B` is a `bit varying` literal.)